# How to color GeoJson polygons using another api?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, leaflet, geojson

I have a GeoJson map file with province ids and coordinates , also I am using another api which tells the color of each province id . I want to set `fillColor` of each polygon accordingly

my GeoJson file (just the first polygon as an example):

```
 [
        {
          "type" : "FeatureCollection",
          "features" : [
            {
              "type" : "Feature",
              "id" : 0,
              "regionColor": "orangeColor",
              "geometry" : {
                "type" : "Polygon",
                "coordinates" : [...]
              },
              "properties" : {
                "FID" : 0,
                "FID_1" : 0
              }
        }
    ]
```

my API (imported as `mockData`):

```
{
    "colors": [
        {
            "id": "0",
            "countryColor": "red"
        },
        {
            "id": "1",
            "countryColor": "orange"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "countryColor": "yellow"
        }
    ]
}
```

my code :

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="mapContainer">      
    </div>
  </div>

</template>
<script> 
import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";
import L from "leaflet";
import geojson from "../components/provinces.json"
import mockData from "./test.json"

export default{
  name: "locationMap",
  data() {
    return{
      center: [32.87255939010237, 53.781741816799745],
    }
  },

methods: {

setupLeafletMap: function () {
  const mapDiv = L.map("mapContainer").setView(this.center, 5);
  L.tileLayer(
    'https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
    {
      attribution: '&copy; <a target="_blank" href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
      // maxZoom: 18,
    }
  ).addTo(mapDiv);

      var myStyle = {
        "fillColor": "#818181",
        "color": "black",
        "weight": 2,
        "opacity": 0.65,
        "fillOpacity": 0.6
      };

    L.geoJSON(geojson,{
     style: myStyle,
    }
   }
  }
mounted() {
    this.setupLeafletMap()
    console.log(mockData.colors[1].id)
  },
}

</script>
```

Comment: I tried using `setColor` but I don't think I used it correctly cause it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

[L.geoJSON](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#geojson) accepts a `style` function to dynamically apply styles based on each feature. You can write a `style` function that maps the feature ID to the color in your dataset. For example:

```js
L.geoJSON(geoJSONData, {
  // The style function receives each feature from your GeoJSON dataset.
  // You can access the feature's properties to lookup the color.
  style: function (feature) {
    const fid = feature.properties.FID,
          color = mockData.colors.find((color) => parseInt(color.id) === fid);

    console.debug(`Feature with id ${fid} has now color ${color.countryColor}`);

    return {
      fillColor: color.countryColor,
      color: "black",
      weight: 2,
      opacity: 0.65,
      fillOpacity: 0.6
    };
  }
}).addTo(map);
```

I created an example with your code and some sample data as a reference, check it out here: https://codepen.io/strfx/pen/XWYNrBM

Hope this helps!